# Css apply background on background image

Tags: css, background

I am currently have two images and I would like to apply a filter or gradient on them :

Html:

```
<div class='category_a tinted'>

</div>
<div class='category_b tinted'>

</div>
```

Css:

```
.category_a{
  background-image : url(...);
}
.category_b{
  background-image : url(...);
}

.tinted{
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 100%);
}
```

However, it background overrides the background-image property. How can I have both the tint and the image (without duplicating the code).

Comment: there is an extra bracket after RGB in ur code

Comment: can u create a fiddle demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on @ChronixPsyc point, a pseudo-element attached to a separate class would achieve this.

You may run into issues with `z-index` if the div has content but this can be fixed.

```css
[class*="category"] {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    border:1px solid red;
    margin: 25px;
}
.tinted > * {
    position: relative; /* required to 'set' z-index */
}

h2 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.category_a {
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/1/);
}

.category_b {
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/2/);
}

.tinted {
        position: relative; /* positioning context */
}

.tinted::before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
}
```

```html
<div class="category_a tinted">
    <h2>Caption</h2>>
</div>

<div class="category_b tinted">
        <h2>Caption</h2>>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    background-image: url(), gradient-goes-here
```

Try this. It ll work

```
    background-image: url(IMAGE), linear-gradient(...Color You Want...)
```

Comment: I will basically end-up duplicating the code by doing so.

Comment: So You want to add fourth css which overwrites first three or what do you mean by without duplicating

Answer (score 0):

If you're using LESS, try something like the below:

```
.category_a:after {
    content:"";
    .tinted; // class with your background;
    position:absolute;
    // Add your top, bottom, left, right here
    z-index:1;
}
```

Or if you're not using LESS, try this

```
.category_a:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    // Add your top, bottom, left, right here
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), 100%);
    z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use `::before`?

Comment: If OP wants the background gradient to appear on top of the images, it makes sense to use after as it adds it at the end of the element.  Using before or after in this instance won't make a difference as the pseudo will be positioned absolutely and should have a z-index

Comment: These are background images so the :after will overlay any content.There is no `z-index` in your example...it might be worth adding that. with the appropriate comment.

Comment: Sorry,  I've added a `z-index` in now